# How can I remove a JS hover function on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found the following js code to swap the background of a parent div by a link in a child div, but the hover state stays in place, rather than returns to the original state, on mouseout. Can anyone help me adjust the code to return the parent div's background after mouse out of the link? Thank you in advance.

```
    $('.background-changer').on('mouseover', 'a', function () {

    var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

    $('.background-changer').css('background-image', background)
});

}); 


    <div id="navBar" style="background: url(images/navigation-background-0.gif);" class="background-changer">
                <div id="navBarCell1"><a href="#" title="Resort" target="_parent" data-background="images/navigation-background-1.gif">Resort</a></div>
</div>

#navBar {
    height: 38px;
    width: 760px;
    float: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#navBarCell1 {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#navBarCell1 a:link {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You should do that in CSS.

Comment: Agreed, use CSS. If you need to trigger behaviors in JavaScript (jQuery in this example), you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, or use the jQuery `hover` function, which allows you to set behavior for both actions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I normally use CSS, but in this case I need to change the parent div's background by hovering over the child div's link, and I can't get it to work with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep what you have but before setting the background to the url of the link, add a data attribute to the parent div with the current background url.  Then bind to a mouseout event and set it back like so:

```
var bgChanger = $('.background-changer');
bgChanger.on('mouseenter', 'a', function () {
var background = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-background') + "')";

bgChanger.data('original-background', bgChanger.css('background-image')).css('background-image', background);
}

bgChanger.on('mouseout', function(){
  bgChanger.css('background-image', bgChanger.data('originalBackground'));
});
```

I haven't tested this but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am getting a syntax error on this line:  bgChanger.on('mouseout', function(){

Comment: @user2770230 try changing it from bgChanger.on() to bgChanger.mouseout(function(){//Content here});

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this with JS you can use a hover function like so:

**[Working Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Qgvxs/)**

```
$('#navBar').hover(function () {
    $('#navBar').css({
        'backgroundImage': 'url( --- )' // image 2
    });
},
function () {
    $('#navBar').css({
        'backgroundImage': 'url( --- )' // image 1
    });
});
```

[API documentation for `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

But as SLaks mentioned in the comments the preferred method would probably be to just use CSS `:hover` like so:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Qgvxs/1/)**

```
#navBar {
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url( --- ); /* image 1 */
    background-size:20px;
}
#navBar:hover{
    background-image: url( --- ); /* image 2 */
}
```

[MDN documentation for `:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)

Comment: Thank you. I can not use the hover function as I am changing the parent div background from a child div's link. Would the JS change for the parent-child div use?

Comment: @user2770230 as long as your selectors are correct you shouldn't have any problems